# CSRF check in Slim using Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csrf, slim

I've been struggling to get my CSRF to work when using Ajax post requests.
I do have multiple requests that would use the same CSRF token. but the problem is that it already fails on the first one that gets executed. (there's only 1 trigger at loading the page)

a brief overview of the code:

Ajax call:

```
var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "http://localhost:3000/locations",
                "method": "POST",
                "headers": {
                    "{{ nameKey }}": "{{ name }}",
                    "{{ valueKey }}": "{{ value }}",
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                }
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (Data) {
```

Middleware:

```
$container['csrf'] = function ($c) {
    $csrf = new \Slim\Csrf\Guard;
    $csrf->setPersistentTokenMode(true);
    return $csrf;
};
$app->add($container->get('csrf'));
```

I've been searching how to solve this for a while now. Almost everywhere I look they tell to set token persistent mode to true and that will solve the problem. Yet when I try this I get the same error I've tried multiple things like regenerating the token before the request but it nothing seems to work at this point.

I'd be very happy if someone could help me solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I found out posting the CSRF values as headers doesn't work.
(postman gave me that idea when filling data there)
instead I had to go create a form and append the CSRF like this

```
                    let form = new FormData();
                    form.append("csrf_name", csrfName);
                    form.append("csrf_value", csrfValue);
                    var settings = {
                      "async": true,
                      "crossDomain": true,
                      "url": "http://localhost:3000/update,
                      "method": "POST",
                      "headers": {
                        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
                      },
                      "processData": false,
                      "contentType": false,
                      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                      "data": form
                    };
```

this worked out for me.

Comment: this answer not helpful, try add explain answer